# Geb Automation Selenium 2.41.0

Tags: firefox, selenium, groovy, spock, geb

I am attempting to run Geb automation scripts however I have recently been running into some issues with automation involving Firefox. Sometimes, some particular scripts will run correctly but at other times they will not. So I thought that this is a driver issue, and I look up and see that the latest selenium driver 2.41.0 provides support for the latest version of Firefox 28.0. So what I did was download the latest selenium driver, and added to my computer's path through the Environment Variables. However, the following error is thrown whenever I try to run an automation script:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Error: Permission denied to access property '_wrapped'
Command duration or timeout: 52 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'reza-PC', ip: '169.254.56.154', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: a587e84b-bcfe-41d3-9283-810beaa6a2c5
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=28.0}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.click(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:376)
    at geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent.click(TemplateDerivedPageContent.groovy:108)
    at LoginPage.loginWithCorrectCredentials(LoginPage.groovy:49)
    at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:194)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
    at UploadScansSpec.setupSpec(UploadScansSpec.groovy:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Error: Permission denied to access property '_wrapped'
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'reza-PC', ip: '169.254.56.154', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.WebElement.clickElement(file:///C:/Users/sam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5133516236203723165webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10310)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/sam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5133516236203723165webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10884)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/sam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5133516236203723165webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10889)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/sam/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5133516236203723165webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
```

I have also upgraded to the latest version of Geb, groovy, and spock. Also worth noting, the automation works fine for chrome and ie.

Comment: Hei Sam, you can follow this link: http://aboutselenium.blogspot.in/2012/02/handling-permission-denied-error-for.html. I had similar experience with "Permission denied to access property '_wrapped'" error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is due to selenium version,I think some thing is not available to selenium for which it is searching for like button or text.So check for that.